# Is uploading straight to Amazon S3 with jQuery file uploader more reliable?

Tags: amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have the blueimp jQuery file uploader on my site for uploading video files.  However, after upload the video files ultimately get sent to S3.

I understand you can upload them directly to S3, but I am mainly considering this for reliability.  I am finding that larger video files are becoming slightly corrupted when uploaded.  The file appears to be all there and fully uploaded, but ffmpeg throws errors on the uploaded file vs. the original.

I am not quite sure why this is, but wondering if sending them straight to S3 might improve the reliability.

Comment: First of all, I would find out if the uploaded file is actually different to the original file. You can do this with a checksum. I would also verify that the correct content-type was set for the object in S3.

Comment: Ah true.  I was just comparing file sizes.  Let me check that.

Comment: If the file sizes are different, the contents are different.

Comment: No the file size is exactly the same

Comment: @jarmod I did a chksum on the two files.  The filesizes are the same, but the checksum numbers are different.  this is the same file.  One was uploaded first via jQuery File Upload though.

Comment: Have you written a server component that receives the uploaded file, saves it locally, then uploads it to S3? I would investigate that code. Any chance you have created the intermediate file in text mode rather than binary?

Comment: Yes, that is how it has been working.  It's pretty much just the UploadHandler provided by the jquery file upload.  It puts the file into a folder and then it gets uploaded to s3.  Unless that uploadhandler is creating the file in text mode then no

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199928/discussion-between-jarmod-and-craig).